# Rust matches! macro behaves unexpectedly in regards to enum

Tags: rust, enums, macros

GIVEN I use the [matches!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) macro
WHEN I try to use it together with enums
THEN it shows unexpected behavior.

See the following minimal example which is also available in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1e612e2e084519f08cfa3c34f8ab85a)

```
pub enum Test {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}

fn main() {
    let x = Test::FIRST;
    let y = Test::SECOND;
    
    println!("{}", matches!(x, Test::FIRST));   // <-- 'true',  as expected
    println!("{}", matches!(x, Test::SECOND));  // <-- 'false', as expected
    
    println!("{}", matches!(Test::FIRST,  x));  // <-- 'true', as expected
    println!("{}", matches!(Test::SECOND, x));  // <-- 'true', NOT as expected
    
    println!("{}", matches!(x, y));             // <-- 'true', NOT as expected
}
```

Is there a simple explanation why `matches!` does not behave as expected and
is there a simple way to compare two `enum` variables in regards to equality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument to `matches!` is a value, the second argument is a *pattern*. The patterns `x` and `y` will always successfully match whatever they are given, and then bind to it as a new variable.

The `matches!` macro will discard this variable as it is not used. You can see this in the warnings that you are getting:

```
warning: unused variable: `y`
  --> src/main.rs:16:32
   |
16 |     println!("{}", matches!(x, y));
   |                                ^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_y`
```

The warning is telling you that `matches!(x, y)` is the same as `matches!(x, _y)`.

---

To compare two `enum` values for equality, you should implement `PartialEq` and compare using the `==` operator:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum Test {
    First,
    Second,
}

fn main() {
    let x = Test::First;
    let y = Test::Second;
    println!("{}", x == y); // false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter, it works. The answer seems obvious to you. Where/How could I have known to implement PartialEq in this case?

Comment: @Finnfalter you could have tried an equality check between the two values, and the compiler would have told you that it requires `PartialEq`.

Comment: What if they don't implement `PartialEq`?

Comment: @detly Things that do not implement `PartialEq` cannot be compared for equality. Things that _cannot_ implement `PartialEq` are usually types for which equality is nonsensical or hard to define in the first place.

Comment: @PeterHall I've encountered plenty of 3rd party libs or generated code that no one has thought to tack on the necessary `#[derive(PartialEq)]` for. It's perfectly possible to write out the entire match statement, it's just a pain that `matches!` is supposed to help with.